# Using a Pure Abstract Data Type as a return?

Tags: c++, c++11

I would like to use a pure ADT as a return argument, as in (summary):

```
class PADT {
public:
   virtual ADT func() = 0;
   virtual int iFun() = 0;
}

class X : PADT {
public:
   virtual PADT func() { return X(); }
   virtual int iFun()  { return 1; }
}

Class Y : PADT {
public:
   virtual PADT func() { return Y(); }
   virtual int iFun()  { return 2; }
}
```

And then, how could I use it?

Comment: C++ does not work this way. You probably need to use `std::shared_ptr`, and dynamically-scoped object.

Comment: You cannot return a virtual type by value and still expect the virtual methods to work. The fact the class is abstract enforces that for you (since there is no "reasonable" default implementation in the base class. You could return a pointer to an allocated instance of `X` or `Y` that has a return type signature of `PADT*`.  You probably want to use `std::shared_ptr`, or `std::unique_ptr`, to simplify lifetime management.

Answer (score 3):

In C++ values have fixes types; they cannot (directly) use the built-in OO runtime polymorphism of C++.

Now you can implement runtime value polymorphic types in C++, such as std function, but they won't be (directly) using the C++ object oriented system.  Std function's `operator()`, copy, and move, and destroy operations are all polymorphic at runtime; none of them are `virtual`.

If that kind of polymorphism is what you want, look into how std function can be implemented.  If you want to use the C++ builtin virtual methods, the  work out how to return smart pointers and work with them.

Answer (score 0):

In order for polymorphism to work in `C++` you have to work with *pointers* or *references*.

It is typical to use *smart pointers* to manage dynamic objects, like a `std::unique_ptr`. This deletes the objects automatically when the pointer goes out of scope so you do not need to remember to do it.

Something like this:

```
class PADT {
public:
    // return a pointer (pref a unique_ptr)
    virtual std::unique_ptr<PADT> func() = 0;
    virtual int iFun() = 0;
};

class X : public PADT {
public:
    virtual std::unique_ptr<PADT> func() { return std::make_unique<X>(); }
    virtual int iFun()  { return 1; }
};

class Y : public PADT {
public:
    virtual std::unique_ptr<PADT> func() { return std::make_unique<Y>(); }
    virtual int iFun()  { return 2; }
};

int main()
{
    X x; // an x
    Y y; // a y

    std::unique_ptr<PADT> padt = x.func();

    std::cout << "x: " << padt->iFun() << '\n';

    padt = y.func();

    std::cout << "y: " << padt->iFun() << '\n';
}
```

**Output:**

```
x: 1
y: 2
```